# Index out of range when removing last row in datatable in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I get an array index out of range exception when removing the last row in a datatable in WPF. Removing other rows is ok, but trying to remove the last row triggers this problem. What is wrong here?

```
public void removeRow(int index)
{
    if (index < 0)
    {
        index = 0;
    }
    myDataTable.Rows.RemoveAt(index);
    myDataTable.AcceptChanges();
}
```

I also tried `selectedDataRow.delete()` and `myDataTable.remove(selectedDataRow)` but they have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

The row number is 0 indexed so you are probably off by one. You could add this to your check

```
if (index < 0)
{
    index = 0;
}
else if (index >= myDataTable.Rows.Count)
{
    index = myDataTable.Rows.Count - 1;
}
```

When a row is removed, all data in that row is lost. You can also call the Delete method of the DataRow class to just mark a row for removal. Calling RemoveAt is the same as calling Delete and then calling AcceptChanges.

Comment: thanks for answering.
this will not delete the row I want, removes the previous row. I guess the last row is not considered as the datatable row! it is just shown in datagrid. sounds strange!

Comment: You might be referring to the last blank row to allow users to add rows? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665048/how-to-disable-the-last-blank-line-in-datagridview

Comment: No problem. I still suggest you add the extra validation to the method to prevent future out of range exceptions.